# The "0" minute is not appearing in current time (JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to coding in general, so apologies in advance if I sound stupid!

I'm currently working on a project regarding a smart mirror. The GUI displays the user's calendar, current time and date etc. However, I'm having issues with the current time aspect of the build.
For some reason, if the minute is "0" (For example "18:05") the current time will appear without the minute e.g. "18:5". Any help will be greatly appreciated! Here's the code below;

```js
function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date(),
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds();
  date = [now.getDate(),
    months[now.getMonth()],
    now.getFullYear()
  ].join(" ");

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = [date, time].join(" / ");

  setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
updateClock();
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: at least `now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()` should be `now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()`

Comment: then you can use something like `now.getSeconds()>=10?now.getSeconds():('0'+now.getSeconds())` to add leading zero to string representation of integer value

Comment: Use `.textContent = ` instead of `.innerHTML = ` as it's much faster because it doesn't invoke the HTML parser or significant DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Add "0" if minutes is < 10

also save now.getMinutes() into a variable so you don't generate it more than once (wasting function calls).

```js
function updateClock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var mins = 5;//set to now.getMinutes()
    mins = mins < 10 ? "0"+mins : mins;
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        time =now.getHours() + ':' + mins, now.getSeconds();
    date = [now.getDate(),
            months[now.getMonth()],
            now.getFullYear()].join(" ");

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = [date, time].join(" / ");

    setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
updateClock();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot now!

Answer (score 0):

`('0'+now.getMinutes()).slice(-2)` this will add zero before and take last 2 digits. So `5` becomes `05` and final result is `05`. `15` become `015` so final result becomes `15`

```
time =now.getHours() + ':' + ('0'+now.getMinutes()).slice(-2)+':'+ ('0'+now.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) depending on your browser support.

```js
function updateClock(element) {
  const now = new Date();
  const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
  }).format(now);

  const time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
  }).format(now);

  element.textContent = `${date} / ${time}`;
}

setInterval(updateClock.bind(null, document.getElementById('time')), 1000);
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```